# Django Product price calculation

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms

Here I am having a product detail.

```
class product(models.Model):

    Product_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    product_description = models.TextField(max_length=170, null=True)
    product_price = models.SmallIntegerField(null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Product_name
```

Depending on the product selection the value "30" has to change dynamically pending on the product. So that It will calculate price automatically. Please help me.

```
if form.is_valid():
    user = form.save(commit=False)
    products = form.cleaned_data['Product']
    Quantity = form.cleaned_data['Quantity']

    shoping_product = product.objects.filter(Product_name= products)
    sub_total = 30 * Quantity
    user.Gst = 30 * (1 + 0.18)
    user.Price = sub_total + user.Gst

    user.save()
    messages.success(request, 'Registration successful.')
    return redirect('home')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

30 is the unit price of the product ?

```
shoping_product = product.objects.filter(Product_name= products).first()
sub_total = shoping_product.product_price * Quantity
user.Gst = shoping_product.product_price * (1 + 0.18)
user.Price = sub_total + user.Gst
```

Comment: Yes 30 is the price of the product.

'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'product_price'. I executed and this was the error which i am getting.

Comment: Yes, you have to get the first item of your **product.objects.filter(...)**,  filter returns a queryset, not an object. I fix my answer